# Custom Route in ASP.NET core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am building an API and I want some action to be hit for the POST request: /api/sections/assign?sectionId=1. But for some reason, the route is not working. Please help.

Here is my code:

```
[Route("/api/[controller]")]
public class SectionsController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("/assign/{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AssignRoom(int sectionId, [FromBody] SaveRoomSectionAssignmentResource resource)
    {
        // Some Code ...
    }
}
```

I want the action to be hit but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("assign/{sectionId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AssignRoom(int sectionId, [FromBody] SaveRoomSectionAssignmentResource resource)
{
          // some code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace SchedulingSystem.Controllers
    {
        [Route("api/Sections")]
            public class SectionsController : Controller
            {
               [HttpPost]
               [Route("assign/{sectionId}")]
               public async Task<IActionResult> AssignRoom(int sectionId, [FromBody] SaveRoomSectionAssignmentResource resource)
               {
                  // some code here
               }
            }
        }
```

use this POST request:- /api/sections/assign/1

Comment: Why use the Route and RoutePrefix attributes? What's the difference?

Comment: RoutePrefix is used as an attribute to set route for the entire controller and Route will be used to set route for the action methods which are created in the controller.